# Changing ASP.NET Website Administration Tool Connection String

Tags: asp.net, connection, database-connection, connection-string, server-configuration

I've **created** user roles with **Asp.net website administration tool**. I want to store these user roles in my table which are stored in SQL server. But the tool has created default connection string and has stored datas in its own table.

I've a `user_role` table with attributes `user_id`, `role_id` and `role_name` in SQL server 2008 R2. How can I connect this table to asp.net website administration tool?

I am using .NET framework 4.0, ASP.net web application, SQL server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3):

The default configuration is defined in your application's web.config file here:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;User Id=yourusername;Password=yourpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

The `<connectionStrings>` section will show you where you are connecting to the database, and the `<membership>` section shows how your membership provider is configured.

So, it sounds like you just need to change the connection string to point to the database that you set up (rather than the default `aspnetdb` database).